# what version of ubutu should I install for upgrade, this is my computers capacity

Tags: upgrade

I now have Release 9.04 (Jaunty)
Kernel Linux 2.6.31-2-686
GNOME 2.26.1
Hardware 
Memory 2.0 GiB
Processor 0: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270 @1.60GHz
Processor 1: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270 @1.60GHz
System Status
Available Disc Space 270.7 GiB

Comment: You're going to want to clean install, not "upgrade".  Backup your data first.

Answer (score 1):

At least 12.10 for support of your (I presume) GMA500. Personally I use Kubuntu and I think you will find Unity or Gnome 3 to be very slow. If you do not like KDE, you can consider Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

NOTE: There is no 3d support available for the GMA500.

Comment: What Version, if I clean install?

Comment: Well you have 2 options, 12.10 or 13.04. 13.04 is in Beta and may have bugs.